# Error: BillingAddress does not support aggregate operator COUNT

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

I am trying to get a  list of Accounts that has the same BillingAddress

I tried to get an aggregateResult however got the error:

> Line: 2, Column: 34
>   HAVING count(BillingAddress)>1 ^ ERROR at Row:5:Column:49 field BillingAddress does not support aggregate operator COUNT'

How can I change my query to get the Accounts with same BillingAddress?

```
Set <String>SameBillingAddress = new Set<String>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [Select count(Id),BillingAddress
                                  From Account 
                                  Where BillingStreet!= null AND 
                                  BillingState!=null AND BillingCity!= null 
                                  AND BillingPostalCode!=Null
                                  Group By BillingAddress
                                  HAVING count(BillingAddress) > 1 
] )
{
    SameBillingAddress.add((String)aggregate.get('BillingAddress'));
}
for (Account acc : [
    SELECT Name, BillingAddress
    FROM Account
    WHERE BillingAddress IN :SameBillingAddress
 ]){
    system.debug(+ acc.BillingAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to aggregate each field individually. Also use `count(Id)` in your `HAVING` clause, just like you have it in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode
FROM Account 
WHERE BillingStreet != null
AND BillingCity != null
AND BillingState != null
AND BillingPostalCode != null
GROUP BY BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank You Adrian. I will test it out and mark it closed.

Comment: You might want to consider changing your query for example to  filter for specific states at a time. Instead of `BillingState != null`, you might use `BillingState = 'Alabama'`, then another where you do `BillingState = 'Alaska'`. Alternatively, you might just filter `BillingState LIKE 'A%'`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson  Should  I  modify  my code as follows  
  Set <ID>SameBillingAddress = new Set<ID>();                                                  
 SameBillingAddress.add((String)aggregate.get('ID'));                                                for (Account acc : [
    SELECT Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity,BillingPostalCode
    FROM Account
    WHERE BillingAddress IN :SameBillingAddress
 ]){
    system.debug(+ acc.BillingStreet + acc.BillingPostalCode);
}